# Pandas scalar value getting and setting: ix or iat?

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I'm trying to figure out when to use different selecting methods in pandas DataFrame. In particular, I'm looking for accessing scalar values. I often hear `ix` being generally recommended. But in [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting)
it's recommended to use `at` and `iat` for fast scalar value accessing:

`Since indexing with [] must handle a lot of cases (single-label access, slicing, boolean indexing, etc.), it has a bit of overhead in order to figure out what you’re asking for. If you only want to access a scalar value, the fastest way is to use the`at`and iat methods, which are implemented on all of the data structures.`

So, I would assume `iat` should be faster for getting and setting individual cells. However, after some tests, we found that `ix` would be comparable or faster for reading cells, while `iat` much faster for assigning values to cells.

Is this behavior documented anywhere? Is it always the case and why does this happen? Does it have to do something with returning view or copy? I would appreciate if someone could put any light on this question and explain what is recommended for getting and setting cell values and why.

Here are some tests using pandas (version 0.15.2).

Just to make sure that this behavior is not a bug of this version, I also tested it on 0.11.0. I do not provide the results, but the trend is exactly the same - `ix being much faster for getting, and iat for setting individual cells`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,2),columns = ['A','B'])
idx = 0

timeit for i in range(1000): df.ix[i,'A'] = 1
timeit for i in range(1000): df.iat[i,idx] = 2

>> 10 loops, best of 3: 92.6 ms per loop
>> 10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop

timeit for i in range(1000): tmp = df.ix[i,'A'] 
timeit for i in range(1000): tmp = df.iat[i,idx] 

>> 100 loops, best of 3: 5.31 ms per loop
>> 10 loops, best of 3: 19.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think the get_value() and set_value() is faster

Comment: Interesting to note the relative differences.  Using pandas 0.14.1, I get the following results, respectively:  1) 10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop  2) 100 loops, best of 3: 12.1 ms per loop  3) 100 loops, best of 3: 5.55 ms per loop  4) 100 loops, best of 3: 9.43 ms per loop

Comment: Looks like iat for getting has improved significantly in recently versions.  With pandas 0.19.1 I still see ix faster than iat for the last 2 timings, but just barely.  Above results are 5.31 vs 19.4 (in version 0.15.2) , but I am seeing 6.01 vs 7.16 (in version 0.19.1).

Answer (score 12):

Pandas does some pretty interesting things with the [indexing classes](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py). I don't think I am capable of describing a simple way to know which to use but I can give some insight on the implementation.

[`DataFrame#ix`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L21) is an [`_IXIndexer`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1171) which does not declare its own [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) or [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__). These two methods are important because they control how values are accessed with Pandas. Since `_IXIndexer` does not declare these methods the [super class `_NDFrameIndexer`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L40)'s are used instead.

Further digging on the `_NDFrameIndexer`'s [`__getitem__`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L62) shows that it is relatively simple and in some cases wraps the logic found in [`get_value`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L65). Then `__getitem__` is close to as fast as `get_value` for some scenarios.

`_NDFrameIndexer`'s [`__setitem__`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L116) is a different story. At first it looks simple but the second method it calls is [`_setitem_with_indexer`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L202) which does a considerable amount of work for most scenarios.

This information suggests that calls to get values using `ix` are limited by `get_value` in the best case and calls to set values using `ix` would take a core committer to explain.

Now for [`DataFrame#iat`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L25) which is an [`_iAtIndexer`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1586) which also doesn't declare its own `__getitem__` or `__setitem__` therefor falling back to its super class [`_ScalarAccessIndexer`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1527)'s implementation.

`_ScalarAccessIndexer` has a [simple `__getitem__`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1534) implementation but it requires a loop in order to convert the key into the proper format. The additional loop adds some extra processing time before calling `get_value`.

`_ScalarAccessIndexer` also has a fairly [simple `__setitem__`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1546) implementation which converts the key the parameters `set_value` requires before setting the value.

This information suggests that calls to get values using `iat` are limited by `get_value` as well as a [for loop](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/077b99e17a090901636844612cec581282607ae7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1602). Setting values with `iat` are primarily limited by calls to `set_value`. So getting values with `iat` has a bit of an overhead, while setting them has a smaller overhead.

**TL;DR**

I believe you are using the correct accessor for an `Int64Index` index based on the documentation but I don't think that means it is the fastest. The best performance can be found using `get_value` and `set_value` directly but they require an extra depth of knowledge in how Pandas DataFrames are implemented.

**Notes**

It is worth noting that the documentation on Pandas mentions that `get_value` and `set_value` are deprecated  which I believe was meant to be [`iget_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#selection-deprecations) instead.

**Examples**

In order to show the difference in performance using a few indexers (including directly calling `get_value` and `set_value`) I made this script:

`example.py`:

```
import timeit


def print_index_speed(stmnt_name, stmnt):
    """
    Repeatedly run the statement provided then repeat the process and take the
    minimum execution time.
    """
    setup = """
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,2),columns = ['A','B'])
idx = 0
    """

    minimum_execution_time = min(
        timeit.Timer(stmnt, setup=setup).repeat(5, 10))

    print("{stmnt_name}: {time}".format(
        stmnt_name=stmnt_name,
        time=round(minimum_execution_time, 5)))

print_index_speed("set ix", "for i in range(1000): df.ix[i, 'A'] = 1")
print_index_speed("set at", "for i in range(1000): df.at[i, 'A'] = 2")
print_index_speed("set iat", "for i in range(1000): df.iat[i, idx] = 3")
print_index_speed("set loc", "for i in range(1000): df.loc[i, 'A'] = 4")
print_index_speed("set iloc", "for i in range(1000): df.iloc[i, idx] = 5")
print_index_speed(
    "set_value scalar",
    "for i in range(1000): df.set_value(i, idx, 6, True)")
print_index_speed(
    "set_value label",
    "for i in range(1000): df.set_value(i, 'A', 7, False)")

print_index_speed("get ix", "for i in range(1000): tmp = df.ix[i, 'A']")
print_index_speed("get at", "for i in range(1000): tmp = df.at[i, 'A']")
print_index_speed("get iat", "for i in range(1000): tmp = df.iat[i, idx]")
print_index_speed("get loc", "for i in range(1000): tmp = df.loc[i, 'A']")
print_index_speed("get iloc", "for i in range(1000): tmp = df.iloc[i, idx]")
print_index_speed(
    "get_value scalar",
    "for i in range(1000): tmp = df.get_value(i, idx, True)")
print_index_speed(
    "get_value label",
    "for i in range(1000): tmp = df.get_value(i, 'A', False)")
```

Output:

```
set ix: 0.9918
set at: 0.06801
set iat: 0.08606
set loc: 1.04173
set iloc: 1.0021
set_value: 0.0452
**set_value**: 0.03516
get ix: 0.04827
get at: 0.06889
get iat: 0.07813
get loc: 0.8966
get iloc: 0.87484
get_value: 0.04994
**get_value**: 0.03111
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into the implementation details! Very interesting info! Yea, seems like set_value and get_value are the best performers. You are right, documentation is a bit confusing whether they are depreciated or not. Recent pandas version documentation (0.15.1) doesn’t explicitly mention it to be deprecated, neither does this document on all API changes:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#api-changes
It only explicitly mentions about iget_value.