# Why not use .values rather than .iat for 6x performance improvement?

Tags: python, pandas

I was surprised at the 6x performance improvement I got by accessing series elements using `my_series.values[0]` rather than `my_series.iat[0]`.

According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting), `.iat` is the recommended way for fast access to scalars.  Am I missing anything by using `.values`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 1000
dct = {'A': np.random.rand(n)}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
s = df['A']
vals = s.values

%timeit -n 10000 val = s.iloc[0]
%timeit -n 10000 val = s.iat[0]
%timeit -n 10000 val = s.values[0]
%timeit -n 10000 vals[0]

**Output**
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.3 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 13.4 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 2.06 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 337 ns per loop
```

Comment: Very similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909034/pandas-scalar-value-getting-and-setting-ix-or-iat?rq=1  Note that loc/iloc are generally recommended over ix nowadays, but I believe that behind the scenes ix works somewhat similar to loc/iloc, so the issues are comparable

Answer (score 3):

Based on a some experimentation, it appears that the speed difference between `iat` and `values` narrows considerably if you have multiple columns (which is usually the case).

```
n = 1000
dct = {'A': np.random.rand(n), 'B': np.random.rand(n) }
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)

%timeit df.iat[n-5,1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.72 µs per loop

%timeit df.B.values[n-5]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.3 µs per loop
```

What may also be interesting is that it can matter whether you access the cell directly, or first select the column, and then the row.

In the case of `iat`, it's better to use it on the full dataframe:

```
%timeit df.iat[n-5,1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.72 µs per loop

%timeit df.B.iat[n-5]
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.4 µs per loop
```

But in the case of `values`, it's better to select the column, and then use `values`:

```
%timeit df.values[n-5,1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.42 µs per loop

%timeit df.B.values[n-5]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.3 µs per loop
```

But in any event, using `values` instead of `iat` seems to offer comparable speed at worst, so there appears to be little value added from `iat` over `values` if you are using position based indexing (unless you prefer the syntax).

Conversely, label based indexing is not possible with `values` and in that case `at` will be much faster than using `loc` in combination with `values`.

(timings above using pandas version 0.18.0)