# How to properly fetch single cells in pandas: loc[index,column] VS get_value(index,column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Which method is better (in terms of performance and reliability) to use in order to fetch single cells from a pandas `DataFrame`: get_value() or loc[]?

Comment: `get_value()` - will be faster and more appropriate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find info in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) in the end:

> For getting a value explicitly (equiv to deprecated df.get_value('a','A'))

```
# this is also equivalent to ``df1.at['a','A']``
In [55]: df1.loc['a', 'A']
Out[55]: 0.13200317033032932
```

but if use it there is no warning.

But if check [`Index.get_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_value.html):

> Fast lookup of value from 1-dimensional ndarray. **Only use this if you know what you’re doing**

So I think better is use [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html), [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html), [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html).

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)

In [93]: %timeit (df.loc[0, 'A'])
The slowest run took 6.40 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 177 µs per loop

In [96]: %timeit (df.at[0, 'A'])
The slowest run took 17.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.61 µs per loop

In [94]: %timeit (df.get_value(0, 'A'))
The slowest run took 23.49 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.36 µs per loop
```

Comment: I don't understand this sentence in docs about `deprecated get_value()`... Pandas itself uses `get_value()` internally - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L77

Comment: To see the difference between iat/iloc, at/loc, and ix see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation)

Comment: @JulienMarrec - thank you. I found also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28980433/2901002)